# How to perform a pull to refresh while automating with EarlGrey?

Tags: earlgrey

Suppose you have a tableView or fileListView, and you would like to perform a pull to refresh action on the same. Tried performing with swipe and scroll, there was no result initially.

Answer (score 7):

```
EarlGrey().selectElementWithMatcher(grey_accessibilityID("some element id")).atIndex(0).performAction(grey_swipeSlowInDirectionWithStartPoint(.Down, 0.7, 0.7))
```

atIndex(0) is context specific. In my case, I had a list view and I hooked on to the first element and did a slow swipe down. 
Similarly, the value '0.7' is also relative, you can change those to 0.1, 0.3, etc and try out yourself.

Comment: Swipe fast just does a fast pull, but you won't see a spinner as well as data updation. It didn't have any effect on my app. But slow with these values I have mentioned for x and y worked.

Comment: It worked, but I needed slightly different values for the start point to get a refresh: grey_swipeSlowInDirectionWithStartPoint(.Down, 0.5, 0.5)

Answer (score 0):

Updated syntax:

```
 EarlGrey.selectElement(
    with: grey_accessibilityID("some element id")
 )
 .atIndex(0)
 .perform(
    grey_swipeSlowInDirectionWithStartPoint(
       .down, 0.7, 0.7
    )
 )
```